# Ubuntu live usb, with persistent memory?

Tags: persistence

is it possible to make my live USB with Ubuntu 15 on it a live persistent memory operating system instead of just a trial/install version which is always the same when i start it?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  When you create the USB with `usb-creator-gtk` there is a slider bar for how big of a persistent file you want.  I believe it is anywhere from 1GB - 4GB.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 currently has a problem where the USB Creator Tool does not work to create an Ubuntu 15.10 Live USB stick at all - you have to use mkusb instead, and that means you can't utilise the persistence option. Unless you really really need it, don't bother with Ubuntu 15.04 as support for that has just finished. Consider using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or wait for 16.04 LTS which is due in April.

Answer (score 0):

Yes once the Live version is up and running there should be an ICON on the desktop you can click to install the OS permanently, follow the instructions.

Comment: Great thanks guy i started it last night n now its finish lets give it a try! Btw i used ubuntu live and used installer to install on sandisk cruizer. My windows is still good now lets try new ubuntu usb

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Ubuntu you could use the pre-installed Startup Disk Creator

[image: startup disk presistent]

On Windows you could simply use [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) (Your Universal Multiboot Integrator).

Comment: Great thanks guy i started it last night n now its finish lets give it a try! Btw i used ubuntu live and used installer to install on sandisk cruizer. My windows is still good now lets try new ubuntu usb